# refresh activity when internet restarts with Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Ok, i'm a beginner, and in first contact with broadcast receiver, even with so much search. Sorry, but i have a project to finish in a few hours. If anyone could help me i would be very very thankful.
This is simple, i suppose. I just want to deploy a function checkNetwork (this is working), when the internet is back.
I have a class that i send an intent throu broadcastReceiver. In my intent, i specefied which class will receive that. This is correct?

```
public class NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    public NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(NetworkHelper.networkIsAvailable(context)){
                    Log.i(TAG, "there is net ");
                    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, NowPlayingMoviesFragment.class);
                    context.startService(serviceIntent);
                    }
        else{
        Log.d(TAG, "wifi is not available");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is when the nowPlayingMoviesFragment (class) receives that:

What to insert there?  ResumeBroadcastReceiver=new ResumeBroadcastReceiver()? I don't know what to put in the intent filter as well.

Bellow is a private class in that nowPlayingMoviesFragment

private class ResumeBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        checkNetwork();
    }
```

Comment: i dont understand what you want

Comment: just ask the main point, your main goal

Comment: My main goal is to detect if there is internet or not, and if has, i want to restart this fragment. To do that i have a refresh method that i call in oncreate view. If i have net, this will be called. But if the net turns off, and on again, this will not be called since the activity(?) already been start. I need a broadcast receiver to listen when the internet is on and call that refresh.

Comment: is your NetworkChangeBroadcastReceiver works?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a couple of different ways. The broadcastReciever can live inside the fragment code if it's only going to be used there, but I've tried to change as little code as possible. To begin with, intercepting connectivity change in the manifest has been deprecated in 7.0 and up so we have to register the receiver manually. I did this in my MainActivity's `onCreate`. `ncbr` is a class level variable.

```
 final IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
 intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
 ncbr = new NetworkChangeBroadcastReciever();
 this.registerReceiver(ncbr, intentFilter );
```

Don't forget to unregister is in your activity's onDestroy

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(ncbr);
}
```

This will run the code in your `onRecieve` if you toggle the 4g or wifi. The issue now is that the receiver doesn't have access to the fragment. An easy way around that is to broadcast your own event when you pass all your tests. We do that with the block below, the rest of your class is unchanged.

```
        // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
        // text of activity by calling method
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            Log.i("Myapp", "Connected!");
            Intent myIntent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction("MyApp.ConnectivityGained"); //change to any unique tag
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
```

Now we need to set up our fragment to listen for this event. I put this code in the fragment's `onCreateView`. `br` is a class level `BroadcastReceiver`

```
br = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent i)
        {
           Log.i("MyApp", "Broadcast Received");
           // your refresh code goes here
        }
    };

LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(br, 
new IntentFilter("MyApp.ConnectivityGained")); //filter has to match whatever you picked in the other broadcast receiver
```

Now just like before we need to unregister the listener when the fragment is destroyed.

```
@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(br);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. Althought it's not working. Something is wrong, i don't know what. I did everything you said. I have although one doubt. This is a fragment, that extends from a Base Fragment where there is a onResume(),  onPause(), onDestroy()...Should i do all this there? instead in NowPlayingMoviesFragment? I just want a autorefesh to happen when the internet turns on. It can be in any other fragment, because when the internet comes again, maybe i am in another fragment, and not have to call thart refresh in here. hummmm Many thanks anyway. Beginners issues...:)

Comment: You can do it anywhere you can call your refresh method from. What issue are you getting? Can you see in your logs where something is failing?